# AWS Boto3 RDS Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Does anyone know if the RDS encryption for MySQL and Postgres is exposed yet in the boto3 code?

Otherwise would anyone know when this might be available or a workaround?

Many thanks.

Comment: I can see that the method is exposed in the AWS CLI:

[AWS RDS Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [create an RDS instance](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#rds.Client.create_db_instance) you can specify the `StorageEncrypted` and `KmsKeyId` parameters to set up encryption for your database. For example:

```
import boto3

rds = boto3.client('rds')
response = rds.create_database(
    DbInstanceIdentifier='mydatabase', AllocatedStorage=20,
    DbInstanceClass='db.m1.medium', Engine='MySQL',
    MasterUsername='dbadmin', MasterUserPassword='PASSWORD',
    StorageEncrypted=True, KmsKeyId='KEYID')
```